# Arrange data that contain matching vlaue in Excel

Tags: excel

I am working on formula of VLOOKUP that works fine. By using this formula I get the column values that are matching. Now I want to separate the non matching value in another column with using formula without non matching value in sequence.

Sheet looks like this.

[image: Worksheet]

Comment: I need green boxes in column M. Thanks

Comment: Is there any solution available or not?